I found these wild prickly plants on a trip in Cambridge, what are they?
I found these beautiful prickly plants in between Cambridge and St Ives, UK. I am wondering what type of plants they are. Some kind of thistles?
The last two pictures are from the same plant.
Does anyone have any idea?




Thank you!
Update:
I found a similar one in Tallinn (Estonia), which seems to be Arctium as learned from one of the commenters:


You've found yourself some of nature's own original Velcro

First and third look like burdock: look at the hooks at the end of the "spines".
Second is completely different: it's a gall on a briar rose.

Burdock, typically Arctium lappa, is a plant well-known to anybody with a long-haired companion animal: it seldom presents a skin-penetration hazard but can be time-consuming when found in e.g. a horse's forelock or a fleece being hand-processed.
Described in detail at https://www.botanical.com/botanical/mgmh/b/burdoc87.html and more recently at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burdock it was formerly used as an ingredient in Dandelion and Burdock, which was promoted as a temperance drink. However latterly it is best known as the inspiration for Velcro (plus the many brands of hook-and-loop fastener which imitate it), famously highlighted by https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rRi8LptvFZY.
Galls, such as the one seen in the second photograph, are common on many plants. However in most cases they are formed as either flat lumps on a leaf, or (in the case of e.g. oak) round "apples" attached to a stem which were historically used for ink preparation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_gall_ink.
The ones that afflict roses, particularly wild briars https://www.botanical.com/botanical/mgmh/r/roses-18.html#wil, are unusually eye-catching due to their size, hairiness, and colouration. They are normally harmless, but the nearby prickles have caused distress to many an unwary person attempting to pick one out of curiosity.
Briars on roses are caused by the presence of a wasp larva, this writer prefers not to speculate on whether there are multiple species and whether the appearance of the gall depends in part on this.

Wow I had never heard or seen anything like that. Is this related to this wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diplolepis_rosae?

While the first and third do have some resemblance to burdock, the burdock plants we had never branched out to look like trees as in the third picture. They looked like rhubarb bushes.

@Brōtsyorfuzthrāx Nothing at all like rhubarb. Leaving aside the form (i.e. rhubarb is not a bush), the burdock shown has round stems while those of rhubarb are crescent shaped; also the flower type of completely different.

Could be Arctium. Though I've never seen one so legged. It's an extremely common weed around here but I don't believe I've seen it flower.
AFAIK it's not poisonous but also not used as foodsee comments. The balls are fun to throw at friends as they are curved in the end thus both don't hurt and stick to cotton clothing.
Your second image seems to be of an entirely different plant. Possibly Rosa canina but it's so infant it's hard to tell.


source of both images

Burdock (Arctium spp.) is used as food, especially the root of the plant. It has "macrobiotic" properties. "Dandelion and burdock" is made into a soft drink that is still available in the UK.

I have just tried the soft drink! It is quite nice. I guess it wouldn't be to everyone's taste, but it kind of reminds me of liquorice. As a Dutch person I am well-acquainted with that flavour
